# C# Attempted to read or write protected memory. OpenGL/OpenTK libraries

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to execute following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Width = 512, Height = 512; //window size
        var CubeSize = 200; // square size
        int left, right, top, bottom;
        left = (Width - CubeSize) / 2;
        right = left + CubeSize;
        bottom = (Height - CubeSize) / 2;
        top = bottom + CubeSize;
        GL.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Color3(255, 0, 0);
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
        GL.Vertex2(left, bottom);
        GL.Vertex2(left, top); 
        GL.Vertex2(right, top);
        GL.Vertex2(right, bottom);
        GL.End();

    }
```

In line `GL.ClearColor` it throws an error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory

Need some help.

Comment: You have to create a [`GameWindow`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.GameWindow.html) see [GameWindowSimple.cs](https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/master/Source/Examples/OpenTK/GameWindow/GameWindowSimple.cs)

Comment: @Rabbid76 it's ok, I added this as `using (var game = new GameWindow(800, 600))` 
it throws an:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use most of the GL methods, you need to be on the GL thread. The best way to tell if you are on a GL thread is if any of the overriden `GameWindow` methods are called by the running `GameWindow`. If you want to change the GL thread, you need to make a new window on a different thread and then use `window.MakeCurrent()`.

If you use it anywhere different ( for example, if you dispose of a texture from a GC finalizer ), you might get that exception.